# How to hold an activity until data is being downloaded/available

Tags: android

I am fairly new to android programming and would like to clarify a scenario. Okay, I have two activities called A & B. When activity A is launched, it requests to download some data in the background and anyway after 3 seconds activity B is launched. Activity A acts like a splash screen. So when B activity is launched, I want to hold and wait until the data is fully loaded so that I can initialize the downloaded data in activity B. At the moment activity B launches even before the data is downloaded. If this is the case, after B is loaded and then data is being downloaded, how would I dynamically load the data in activity B? 
Also, is there a way to hold the onCreate in activity B until the data is being downloaded?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: start activity A (splashscreen), start downloading, when downloading is done, finish activity A and start activity B

Comment: That would be a bad design. You shouldn't perform any long waiting process in UI thread, that would result in ANR. One solution can be to create an asynctask to download in Activity A and once download is finished, call Activity B passing downloaded data.

Comment: To answer another question, you can always refresh existing view with new information by calling invalidate() method for the view. In case of ListView, call notifyDataSetChanged() method of ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using AsyncTask for Background Data Download. if yes then you simply start activity B from onPostExecute() method of asyncTask.

you can create seprate Thread or innerclass

```
    public class ThreadCutFiles extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Boolean>{

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Context context;
    private Handler handler;

    public ThreadCutFiles( Context context, Handler handler ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setTitle("File Manager");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Copying Files...");      
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
        //ur downloading code
        return true;

    }   

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How they would require would be to load activity B and the show the progress bar or whatever since activity A acts as a splash screen. so i need to load activity B. after that onCreate can i hold until the data is being download?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using AsyncTask, you can create a callback in activity B that you call in the onPostExecute of the AsyncTask passing the downloaded data to activity B. 
This way you only need to put a loading dialog in activity B onCreate, and take care of loading the data in the callback.

A:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
    //start download task
    ActivityB b = new ActivityB();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), b.getClass()));
    new Task(b.new DownloadCallback()).execute();
   }

 }
```

B:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    //show a progress dialog
    return super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
}

private void loadData(/*Your data*/){
    //Load your data
    System.out.println("data loaded");
}

public class DownloadCallback {

    public void onFinish(/*Your data*/) {
        loadData(/*Your data*/);
    }

   }

}
```

Task:

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object>{//Change the Object to whatever your data is

private DownloadCallback callback;

public Task(DownloadCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Download data here
    //Change the Object return value to whatever your data is
    return true;
}   

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    //Change the Object to whatever your data is and pass to the finish method
    callback.onFinish(/*Your data*/);
  }
 }
```

Comment: how would i know when to call the onPostExecute of the AsyncTask from activity B?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement either Loader (prefered) or Async Task for loading the data in Activity A. When the data loading is completed, in onLoadFinished or onPostExecute open activity B and pass in the downloaded data with the intent. I would suggest to show the loading icon in Activity A so users know your app is doing some work in the background.

Comment: How they would require would be to load activity B and the show the progress bar or whatever since activity A acts as a splash screen. so i need to load activity B. after that onCreate can i hold until the data is being download?

Comment: Yes You can use activity A as splash screen only and use loader, async task in activity B to download data. What do you mean by hold until the data is downloaded? If you do not want user to click back and exit the app when the downloading is running, you can show progress dialog and make it not cancelable. It won't stop user to press Home button and back to Home screen though